# Practical question about a fixpoint

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $c\in \Bbb R^n$ be some fixed vector and $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ be a fixed matrix with non-negative elements. Consider the map $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^n$ given by
$$
  f^i(x^1,\dots,x^n) = 
  \begin{cases}
    1,&x^i\geq c^i \\
    0, &x^i<c^i.
  \end{cases}
$$
By abusing notation, why may think that $f$ is a vector-valued indicator function $f(x) = 1_{\{x\geq c\}}$. Consider further the following dynamics:
$$
  x_{k+1} = Af(x_{k}). \tag{1}
$$
Clearly, not matter where we start, it takes only finitely many iterations (at most $n$) to converge to a fixpoint of $Af(\cdot)$. I wonder, however, whether there is a handy formula for such a fixpoint given the initial value $x_0$.

Please, feel free to retag.

**Updated:** let me elaborate on what I know. Denote $F(x) = Af(x)$. Note that since $A$ has non-negative elements only, it holds that $x_{k+1}\leq x_{k}$ for $k\geq 1$ where the inequality shall be understood as an element-wise one. Since $f$ is a monotone function, $f(x_{k+1})\leq f(x_{k})$ as well, thus there are two cases.

1. If $f(x_{k+1}) = f(x_k)$ then 
   $$
      F(x_{k+1}) = Af(x_{k+1}) = Af(x_k) = x_{k+1}
    $$
   and thus $x_{k+1}\in \mathsf{Fix}(F)$.
2. It $f(x_{k+1})\neq f(x_k)$, then for some $1\leq i\leq n$ it holds that $f^i(x_k) =1$ but $f^i(x_{k+1}) = 0$.

Since $f$ most $n$ components, the case 2. can happen at most $n$ times. In fact, I know that 
$$
  \mathsf{Fix}(F|x_0) = F^m(x_0)
$$
where $m$ is a number of non-zero components of $f(x_0)$. I wonder, though if there is a better formula.

Comment: Nice question, +1. Your clearly and your at most $n$ are a bit short. I'm afraid there are too many (well, not so many) cases to consider to get a single formula.

Comment: @julien: thanks, I've updated to make it more clear

Comment: @julien: what do you mean by the first claim?

Comment: @julien: oh, sorry - I should have mentioned that it holds for $k\geq 1$

Comment: Oh, I see, I did not go to $x_2$... Deleting.

Comment: @julien: ah, but that was a very valuable comment!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the special case where $c=0$. Consider the digraph of $A$. If ${\cal I}$ is the index set of a [strongly connected component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) of the graph, then the vector $x=\mathbf{1}_{\cal I}$ is a fixed point of $Af$. More generally, fixed points of $Af$ are generated from index sets of strongly connected components of the digraph of $A$. Since there are no formulae to determine whether $A$ is [reducible](http://planetmath.org/ReducibleMatrix.html) or determine how $A$ can be reduced (there are computer algorithms for doing so, though), I don't see there is any handy formula to determine the fixed points of $Af$.